# How does mod_rewrite work with phar?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, phar

I made a phar archive out of my web application source directory. The directory contains 'css' and 'js' directories as well. The static files are addressed as /css/xyz.css etc. in html. When I try to access the application the html is loading fine but the static files are not. I tried adding apache rewrite rule which maps /css/xyz.css to /app.phar/css/xyz.css but that doesn't work. Everytime I hit

```
http://hostname/css/xyz.css
```

it is loading index.php.

Do I have to modify all static file references to /app.phar/css/xyz.css ? Static file urls relative to phar file are working fine.

Also, is mod_rewrite completely unusable when using phar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`mod_rewrite` is an Apache module. As soon as Apache runs the `.phar` file via PHP, it's all in PHP's hands. You are responsible for sending out the files properly.

[Phar::webPhar()](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.webphar.php) has a `$rewrites` parameter that lets you simulate mod_rewrite on your own from within the `.phar`.